# Passing a procedure arguments to a trigger

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have a table say:

```
CREATE TABLE comment (
    comment_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    content varchar
);
```

and another:

```
CREATE TABLE comment_tree (
    ancestor integer NOT NULL,
    descendant integer NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ancestor, descendant),
    FOREIGN KEY (ancestor) REFERENCES comment (comment_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (descendant) REFERENCES comment (comment_id)
);
```

Now I have a procedure which insert a new comment as a child of another comment:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE add_comment(content varchar, parent_id integer) AS $$
DECLARE
    cid integer;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO comment (content) VALUES (content)
    RETURNING comment_id INTO cid;

    INSERT INTO comment_tree (ancestor, descendant)
    VALUES (parent_id, cid);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But I want to know if it is possible to pass the `parent_id` to a trigger when I call the procedure instead of inserting into `comment_tree` inside the procedure?

Comment: To question add:  Where is `id` coming from or what does it represent?

Comment: The `id` is actually a parent id for a closure table.

Comment: Is it coming from `my_table` or somewhere else?

Comment: It is not a column from `my_table`. It is given when I call `my_proc`.

Comment: Perhaps you can use [session variables](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/97095/set-session-custom-variable-to-store-user-id) and then access the variable from inside the trigger.

Comment: A  trigger function/procedure cannot have a argument declared in the `CREATE ... PROCEDURE`. You can pass a argument in the `CREATE TRIGGER ... my_trigger()` and it will be available as `TG_ARGV[]` per here [plpgsql trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html). This does not work well for dynamic values, so you will probably need in the procedure something like: `SELECT into tbl_id id form some_table` where `tbl_id` is set up in the `DECLARE` section.

Comment: This seems to be the basic *XY problem*. **You need  to describe the business issue not how you are trying to solve it.**   The `id` you need **cannot** be directly passed to the trigger. It has to be either in the table row processed or selected within the trigger. While you can pass parameters to a trigger (see TG_ARGV[] in [Trigger Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/plpgsql-trigger.html)) they are static and are the same for each call. Please update your question, not in a comment.

Comment: How are determining what the `parent_id` is?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass an arbitrary variable directly to a trigger. You can use a temporary table that simulate a kind of pipe. Create a temporary table with the value you want to pass in the procedure:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE add_comment(content varchar, parent_id integer) AS $$
DECLARE
    pid integer;
BEGIN
    CREATE TEMP TABLE my_temp_table AS SELECT parent_id;
    INSERT INTO comment (content) VALUES (content)
    RETURNING comment_id INTO pid;
    DROP TABLE my_temp_table;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then you can use it in the trigger fired after insertion:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION after_insert_on_comment()
RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO comment_tree (ancestor, descendant)
    SELECT parent_id, new.comment_id
    FROM my_temp_table;
    RETURN null;
END $$;
```

Test it in [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/0qCnIrZQ)